# Move an object with a given speed

Tags: c++, sfml

Here's an example of an if-statement where depending on what keystroke is pressed it will move to a certain position. I have also googled the "move" command in SFML and it takes two arguments.

```
Move the object by a given offset.

This function adds to the current position of the object, unlike setPosition which overwrites it. Thus, it is equivalent to the following code:

object.setPosition(object.getPosition() + offset);
```

Here is the code:

```
if ( key.code == Keyboard::Key::W )
{
    sprite.move (0, -speed);
}
else if ( key.code == Keyboard::Key::S )
{
    sprite.move (0, speed);
}
else if ( key.code == Keyboard::Key::A )
{
    sprite.move (-speed, 0);
}
else if ( key.code == Keyboard::Key::D )
{
    sprite.move (speed, 0);
}
```

---

However I dont understand the arguments. `speed is defined as a float with the value 4.0`.What does sprite.move(0,-speed) mean. I understand we start at 0 but how do we move up if speed is negative? Shoudn't be move down if its negative and up if its positive? Same goes for A and D. I cant draw a picture in my brain where these arguments make sense. Can someone please througly explain?

Comment: q.v. the SFML coordinate system: https://www.reddit.com/r/sfml/comments/d7fqdy/sfml_rendering_system/

Comment: Ok makes more sense now for W and S but not for A and D. If we have the the code for keystroke A which is (-speed,0). Shoudnt it go to the right? We start at -4 and move to 0 on the x-axis which is to the direction right.

Comment: For WASD, the usually directions are NWSE.  W (A key) moves to the left (westward).  Unless you are in Australia.

Comment: Yea I understand that. If you press A you should go left. But the argument itself doesn't make sense which is (-speed,0). Isnt this argument indicating that we are going from a negative x value to 0 which is to the right? I dont understand the arguments and I dont understand how (-speed,0) makes us go left.

Comment: *Isnt this argument indicating that we are going from a negative x value to 0 which is to the right?*  No.

Comment: So what is it indicating? How does (-speed,0) mean we are going left?

Comment: If your current position is (50, 50), and you move (-4, 0), your next position will be (50 + -4, 50 + 0), which is (46, 50).  The next position will be to the left of the current position.  Given the SFML coordinate system.